# Android Localization query

Tags: java, android, localization, number-formatting

I have been working on localisation for my app and cant seem to find any information about how to handle decimal values and dates from different locals to store in sqllite.

for example:
German decimal 123,53
Uk decimal     123.53

So how do you convert from an edittext field to a valid decimal. At the moment I have my code outputting to a textview rather than sql just for testing. The below code works great when using UK decimal but if I use the german decimal it fails!!

```
 Configuration sysConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
 Locale curLocale = sysConfig.locale;
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(curLocale);
 String convertedString = nf.format(Double.parseDouble(EditTextField.getText().toString()));

 TextView showLocalisedNumeric;
 showLocalisedNumeric = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TestNumericValue);
 showLocalisedNumeric.setText(convertedString);
```

I have not started with dates yet but I am assuming converting dates for is more straight forward.

Comment: `how to handle decimal values and dates from different locals to store in sqllite.` - You store the values in a format which is understandable to SQLite. For dates, the valid format is a `Time String`, as defined in https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html. How you show it to the user is another question. You'll probably use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Thanks but I already understand that aspect, what I am asking is how to convert it to that format from for example 123,45 to 123.45 without using a replace method

Comment: Store the decimal values in a REAL field. Then show it to the user using a [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

After some time working on this I found the solution for localisation, taking a value from input and parsing it to a format that can be understood by SQLlite - For this exercise and to reduce code I have just set it to output to a text view.

```
 // set initial value to variables
    String convertedString = "";
    double parsedValue = 0.0;

    //get value from text field
    EditText EditTextField  =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.TestNumericValueEntered);
    String valueFromInput = EditTextField.getText().toString();

    //Get current Locale from system
    Configuration sysConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale curLocale = sysConfig.locale;

    //Set number formats
    NumberFormat nf_in = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(curLocale);
    NumberFormat nf_out = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.UK);

    //try to parse value, otherwise return error message
    try {
        parsedValue = nf_in.parse(valueFromInput).doubleValue();
        // use nf_out.setMaximumFractionDigits(3) to set max number of digits allowed after decimal;
        convertedString = nf_out.format(parsedValue);
    }catch(ParseException e){
        convertedString = "Unable to translate value";
    }
    //Output result
    TextView showLocalisedNumeric;
    showLocalisedNumeric = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TestNumericValue);
    showLocalisedNumeric.setText(convertedString);
```

As I was adding this answer I realised that a nice addition to the code would be to check if the current locale is the same as the one you plan to parse to, if so then the conversion(parsing) can be skipped.